# Firefox "TypeError: all[i] is undefined"

Tags: javascript, firefox

I have a browser based service manual for my Jeep. Works great in IE but not Firefox. Basically there is a TOC that you can expand and drill down into sub topics, e.g.

- [+] Clutch
- [+] Cooling
- [+] Electrical

But Firefox will throw the following error when clicking on the [+] beside the main topics:

```
TypeError: all[i] is undefined
itcToc.js line 10
if( "UL" == all[ i ].tagName )
```

Here is the code in itcToc.js:

```
var eCurrentUL, eCurrentLI, eUL, tempIndex, syncIndex = null;
var eTagName, eSrc, eImgIndex, eSynchedNode = null;
var tempImgIndex = '0';

function getNextULNS(eSrc)
{
    var all = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
    for(var i = tempIndex; i < all.length; i++)
    {
        if( "UL" == all[ i ].tagName )
        {
        eImgIndex = all[tempIndex - 2];
            return all[ i ];
        }   
        else if( "LI" == all[ i ].tagName )
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

I'm a mechanic so tried my best to troubleshoot. If I replace i with an integer on line 10 it will get past this and error on the next if statement at line 15, which has similar syntax.

Is this a variable scope issue? Seems like Firefox does not like var i in the if statement despite be defined in the for statement.

Comment: What's the version of IE on which this code works ?

Comment: IE includes/included comments in `document.getElementsByTagName("*")`. Relevant? Anyways, the existence of `getNextULNS` seems like a bad thing. What does the HTML look like?

Comment: Note that `var eCurrentUL, eCurrentLI, eUL, tempIndex, syncIndex = null;` sets `syncIndex` to `null` and nothing else. Doesn’t seem intentional, but it’s not as if initializing things to `null` is generally useful anyways.

Comment: shouldn't you use `document.all` instead of `document.getElementsByTagName("*")`?

Comment: @Mr_Green: The correct answer is to use neither ever

Comment: @minitech ya that is what I understood from this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2095966/document-getelementsbytagname-or-document-all#comment2031597_2095966). Then what should we use instead?

Comment: @Mr_Green: Something actually appropriate for the job. I’m not really sure what’s going on here, but it seems like the `eSrc` argument should be used in some fashion…

Answer (score 1):

You must set `tempIndex` to a valid number instead of `undefined` if you want `all[ i ]` to work for the first iteration.

For example

```
var tempIndex = 0;
```

---

With the friends of the JS room, we tested `[0,1][undefined]` on IE versions 7 to 10 and it always gave us `undefined`. So either you're testing on an older browser or there's something missing in the question.

Answer (score 0):

`tempIndex` is not initialized at the begining of the for loop, causing `i` to be `undefined` as well.

Answer (score 0):

`var i = tempIndex`: tempIndex hasn't been defined anywhere. Unless you mean `tempImgIndex` in which case you got the variable name wrong. And if it's meant to be tempImgIndex then it needs to be `var tempImgIndex = 0` not `var tempImgIndex = '0'`.

Comment: '0' would be silly but would work (for the first and second iteration).